# Nagios check_ntp_peer not working

Tags: linux, debian, nagios, ntp

I am running a virtualized (vmware) debian (2.6.26-2-686) which I monitor through Nagios. Lastly, I am getting the following Critical error (reported by the _check_ntp_peer_ script):

```
    NTP CRITICAL: Server not synchronized, Offset unknown
```

It calls my attent

```
ion that none of the lines outputted by the _ntpq –no_ command has a star (*)

     remote           refid      st t when poll reach   delay   offset  jitter
==============================================================================
 200.144.121.33  193.204.114.232  2 u    1   64    1  187.298  -34742.  32.024
 146.164.53.65   200.20.186.75    2 u    2   64    1  185.574  -34716.   0.001
 200.160.0.8     200.160.7.186    2 u    1   64    1  186.229  -34734.   0.001
 187.49.33.13    .INIT.          16 u    -   64    0    0.000    0.000   0.001
```

Any clue?
Here is the *ntp.conf*

```
    tinker panic 0

    driftfile /var/lib/ntp/ntp.drift

    statistics loopstats peerstats clockstats
    filegen loopstats file loopstats type day enable
    filegen peerstats file peerstats type day enable
    filegen clockstats file clockstats type day enable


    server 0.debian.pool.ntp.org iburst dynamic
    server 1.debian.pool.ntp.org iburst dynamic
    server 2.debian.pool.ntp.org iburst dynamic
    server 3.debian.pool.ntp.org iburst dynamic

    restrict -4 default kod notrap nomodify nopeer noquery
    restrict -6 default kod notrap nomodify nopeer noquery

    restrict 127.0.0.1
    restrict ::1
```

So, any idea of what the problem could be?

Thanks in advance,

Wilmer

Comment: Can you include your check_command?

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problems on ubuntu and ntp. Time was drifting off dramatically and nagios reported NTP CRITICAL: Offset unknown.
Check for status of your vmware timesync

```
#vmware-toolbox-cmd timesync status
Disable
```

Enable it if you notice it is disabled.

```
#vmware-toolbox-cmd timesync enable
Enabled
```

Helped in my case. May be helpful in yours too. I think it is not in accordance with vmware best practices but it works.